# Can you explain how oauth2 authorization code flow with PKCE works and why it provides more security for browser clients?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Oauth2 implicit flow is not recommended anymore (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-10) for browser clients and should be replaced by Authorization code with PKCE. Why is the latter more secure and how does it work in this kind of clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) it's clear how public clients can use Authorization Code from now on:

```
                                             +-------------------+
                                             |   Authz Server    |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ---->|               | |
   |        |       + t(code_verifier), t_m  | | Authorization | |
   |        |                                | |    Endpoint   | |
   |        |<-(B)---- Authorization Code -----|               | |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   | Client |                                |                   |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(C)-- Access Token Request ---->|               | |
   |        |          + code_verifier       | |    Token      | |
   |        |                                | |   Endpoint    | |
   |        |<-(D)------ Access Token ---------|               | |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
                                             +-------------------+
```

To sum up: By using PKCE the Authorization Server can now verify that the client that requests an authorization code and the one that wants to exchage it for an access token is the same.

(A) The client generates a code verifier string (`code_verifier`) applies a transformation (`t_m`) to it and sends the result of the transformation (`t(code_verifier)`)) and the transformation function (`t_m`) to the auth server.

(B) The auth server records `t(code_verifier)` and  `t_m` and answers with an authorization code.

(C) When C request an access token, it sends both the authorization code and the `code_verifier`. The Auth server applies `t_m` to this `code_verifier` and compares its result with the stored `t(code_verifier)` to verify the integrity of the communications.